# FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage not working

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

`FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage` doesn't work. I followed the official docs. I use the version: `firebase_messaging: ^14.2.1`

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}

void main() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp()
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
}
```

This is how I send my fcn through cloud functions:

```
admin.messaging().sendMulticast({
        tokens: [user.fcmToken!],
        apns: {
          payload: {
            aps: {
              "mutable-content": 1,
              "content-available": 1,
            },
          },
        },
        notification: {
          body: body,
          title: title,
        },
        data: {
          hello: "world?!",
        },
      });
```

I can see the Push-Notification popping up on my device, but `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage` doens't get invoked. Any ideas where the problem could be?

Comment: Any solution found for this?

Answer (score -1):

I think you forgot to add `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()`:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // Try to add this
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
}
```

Comment: Tried it, still same result

Comment: did you initialized your  notification package ?

Comment: and what the package name for notification ?